# quick insert SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I learn SQLite in Android. And I try create universal method who insert to data base. Its **slow insert**:

```
 public long addVlues(String tableName, ContentValues cv) {
        long result = db.insert(tableName, null, cv);
        return result;
    }
```

But its method universal, i can use it when i want. Example:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("name", "test");
dao.addVlues("daoTest", cv); //this i calling method addValues
```

Its good and simple code(for me), but its slow.

Bellow **fast insert** code:

```
public void addValueTest(String tableName) {
        String sql = "insert into "+ tableName + " (id, name) values (?, ?);";

        db.beginTransaction();
        SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            stmt.bindString(i, "name");

            stmt.clearBindings();
            Log.e("qqq", String.valueOf(i));
        }

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

But for each table i need create single method, it increases code. I have question. How create universal **fast insert** method?

Comment: `for each table i need create single method` **False**. You pass the tableName as string. 1 method for all (If they have the same structure). Or simply pass the field names as well. And wouldn't it be even faster, if you remove that 1000 steps loop? It looks completely useless. And so does the transaction.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thanks for answer. In this example i have `tableName`. But If structure each table different?

Comment: I don't understand **Иге**

Comment: @FrankN.Stein sorry, its `But`

Comment: No, if the table structure differs and you can't parametrize the differences, then, no - you will have to write several methods. Or maybe add a control on the table name and construct the proper SQL command accordingly.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein  I'm understood, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
public void addValueTest(String tableName, String[] values)
{
    String sql = "";

    if (tableName.equalsIgnoreCase("TableA"))
    {
            sql = "insert into "+ tableName + " (TableA_FieldA, TableA_FieldB) values (?, ?);";
    }
    else if (tableName.equalsIgnoreCase("TableB"))
    {
            sql = "insert into "+ tableName + " (TableB_FieldA, TableB_FieldB, TableB_FieldC) values (?, ?, ?);";
    }

    //else if ...
    //else if ...
    //else if ...
    //else if ...

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(sql, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Table and Field names are obviously just for example.